# Get all rows from a column and use all to select rows from another table

Tags: c#, sql-server, listbox

I have two tables. How do I use the rows selected with the code below

```
var query = "SELECT ID FROM EmpInfo WHERE Status = @Status;
```

to fill a listBox with a select query using the rows obtained.

```
var query2 = "SELECT Code From DataInfo WHERE ID = @ID;
```

Since it has to be dynamic, I don't think I can use SQL Reader to set it as variables.

Comment: Are you consider joining these tables? using SQL JOINS

Comment: @un-lucky while a join could be made to work, I think using `IN` with a subquery works better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use only one Sql statement e.g.

```
string sqlqry="SELECT Code FROM DataInfo WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM DataInfo WHERE Status=@Status)";
```

and then fill the listbox like in the following:

```
using (SqlDataAdapter myadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlqry, connection))
            {            
                // fill a data table
                var t = new DataTable();
                myadapter.Fill(t);

                // Bind the table to the list box
                listBox1.DisplayMember = "NameOfColumnToBeDisplayed";
                listBox1.ValueMember = "NameOfColumnToUseValueFrom";
                listBox1.DataSource = t;
            }
```

Hope these help.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Just what I needed!

Answer (score -1):

You may get the rows in two separate variable and based on the condition you can load or reload the list box accordingly.
This may be a good option if the number of rows is less. If data set is large then based on the condition fetch the data set fresh and load the list box. Keeping a large data set in memory will not be a good option.

Comment: How does this address the question of using one query to define the condition in another query?

Comment: Sorry about that, I understood the question wrong, i thought you wanted to load both the results in the list box dynamically based on certain condition. The answer by @stevethegrk is good.